# Directshow does not work well on windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: windows, directshow.net

I created a small app that capture video from lifecam camera and grab image. It works well on window xp,7 32bits, but on window 7 64bits sometimes connect to camera failed and timeout grabbing image. I don't know that whether directshow api work well on window 7 64bits or not?Thank for any helping to make this problem clearly.

Comment: It may be a problem with the 64-bit driver for the camera rather than a DirectShow problem.

Comment: you mean that the 64-bit driver is not really compatible with directshow?

Comment: DirectShow works excellently on Windows 7 64-bit!

Comment: try to build your application as x86 instead of AnyCPU.